# FocusVisualStyle not working in wpf custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I desinged some custom controls in WPF like CustomWindow, CustomButton and etc, When i use this controls in other projects, FocusVisualStyle not working for all controls (both WPF built-in controls and my custom control). how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you use Custom Window, the ContentPresenter outer layer in the form Window Style must be added with AdornerDecorator. The controls inside the Window will display FocusVisualStyle.

```
<Style TargetType="xxxWindow">
    ...
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </AdornerDecorator>
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: This is also important for Snoop (https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) to properly highlight the selection with a red rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that FocusVisualStyle gets applied only by focus via keyboard(Tab key). To cover other cases triggers may help.

Comment: right, but when i press tab key, focusvisualstyle not working on bulit-in controls too.

Comment: Could you please provide some code(XAML part) to get the picture better? BTW, so if you use yours controls FVS stops working for custom and built-in controls?